# String containing comma inputting in to the csv file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to input in to the csv file.
My input is as shown below
String string="hi,this is user";
but when i am inputing in to the csv file the comma is taken as delimiter and it is written in two cells. "hi" in one cell and "this is user" in another cell.
But i want the whole string to be in one cell.
How can i achieve this.
Please help me.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/Workspace/Sample2.csv");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);

String names="[hasds,jash.jahd,jash]";
    out.append(names);
    out.flush();
}
```

Comment: Are you using some lib to do this work? Show us the related code to this import process.

Comment: If you are not using a lib, you could wrap the string in quotes. Not a Java question.

Comment: FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/Workspace/Sample2.csv");
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
 String names="hi,this is user";
  out.append(names);
  out.flush();
 }

Comment: @user2243525 Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: *Please* use a CSV library for this task. Programmers who have no idea about how a file format works and try to roll their own implementation are responsible for a great number of headaches among other programmers who have to handle the messed-up files these ill-advised attempts have produced. They might even have to resort to using regular expressions (the horror!)...

Answer (score 33):

Since you're writing a `csv` file, with `comma` delimiter, and your text happens to have a `comma` in it as well, you need to wrap your text within **double quotes**.

```
String names = "\"hi,this is user\"";
```

**Note** that to wrap your text within double quotes, you need to escape the double quotes as well!

**Update:-** A sample code snippet to wrap your string within double quotes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "abcd";
    System.out.println(test); // prints abcd
    test = appendDQ(test);
    System.out.println(test); // prints "abcd"

}

private static String appendDQ(String str) {
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
}
```

Comment: u mean, the string has to be appended with doublequotes??

Comment: wrapped - begin and end with double quotes(in the string).

Comment: check the update! Pass your string to this method & then write it to the file!

Comment: but those doublequotes should not be in my string

Comment: If the string itself contained double-quotes, wouldn't those need to be escaped as well?

Comment: AFAIK if the string contained double quotes, that would already be escaped! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Example from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values 1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the data is properly escaped. Commas and double-quotes require special handling. I would highly recommend using a library to take care of all details of properly escaping csv data for you. Take a look at [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).