# Escaping ',' in CSV Writing not working

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I tried as per below link solution
[String containing comma inputting in to the csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103224/string-containing-comma-inputting-in-to-the-csv-file)

```
for(String data : getCSVData())
{
   if (data != null && data.contains(",")) {
        data = "\"" + data + "\"";
   }
}
```

but if data is like 1,234(String) the generation like this **""1,234""**. so this data put in 2 different cells.

**The output like below**

[image]

Comment: Even though you can surely sort it out yourself I tend to use already provided libraries. Luckily there is one cool library from Apache for CSV: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: Are you using a library to write the read/write CSV data? It looks like your data is already within "s. In that case, you can add another check something line data.startsWith(") to the if condition.

Comment: If you are not using a library, and all your data is in the form "x,xxx","x,xxx" you can try splitting the like by `","`

Comment: Why put 2 double quotes at a side ? put only single double quote

Comment: If I correctly understand, you are *writing* the CSV file. If the file is comma separated, and uses `"` as quoting character, `"1,234", "5,789"` is correctly seen as two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping with double quotes should make it work, may you not are updating the collection from your getting the CSV data to reflect the changes. Please see below code working fine for me.

```
try {
            List<String> csvData = new ArrayList<String>();
            csvData.add("test");
            csvData.add("test,ing");
            csvData.add(",testing");

            List<String> newCsvData = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : csvData) {
                if(str.indexOf(",") >= 0){
                    str = "\""+str+"\"";
                }
                newCsvData.add(str);
            }

            String csv = StringUtils.join(newCsvData, ',');

            System.out.println(csv);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D://filename.csv");

            out.println(csv);

            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @sivakumar .. Did this helped?