# comma seperated escaping for a value while writing in csv

Tags: java, csv

I am writing some values in csv file but the value containing commas get split into >1 once
e.g. a,b,c is one value and should appear in 1 cell but it's appearing in 3 cells.

```
writer.append(node.getLongName());
```

this is how I am writing data into csv files using FileWriter. If node.getLongName() gives me value having commas then value is split according to internal comma.
Can anyone please tell how to make this work and avoid splitting of value.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103224/string-containing-comma-inputting-in-to-the-csv-file

Comment: normally in these case you need another separator for your csv. I can't tell if you are using some library from the code you posted but you need to change your separator. Usually using double quotes " to wrap a string and a semicolon ; or a pipe | to separate values will do the trick, so that the text will look like this: "a";"b";"a,b,c" or "a"|"b"|"a,b,c"

Comment: Quoting the field is a common solution. But it requires your reader to support this quoting. Why not choosing dedicated CSV libs like http://commons.apache.org/csv/

Comment: Please provide some more details of your source data , in order to help you more precisely

Answer (score 0):

You are writing in to a CSV file but do you know out of your source file which fields should not be separated. If you do then you can change the seperator for that field from comma to some other seperator like '+' and than append with the other element of the CSV. As an example:

```
 10/09/2016, cycling club,(sam+1000+oklahoma),(henry+ 1001+california),( bill+1002+NY)
```

Here inside the parenthesis It has the details of students. They were command separated before but I changed it to plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Although is can be manipulated *by hand* for trivial tasks, [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is tricky as soon as you need to process delimiter or new line escaping.

Unless you want to do the heavy testing yourself for all corner cases, you best bet is to rely on a well known CSV library like [the one from apache](http://commons.apache.org/csv/).

Here it is still simple enough (assuming you only need to escape commas), and the common usage is to quote fields containing blanks or delimiters. That means to not write `a,b,c` but `"a,b,c"`:

```
writer.append("\"" + node.getLongName()+ "\"");
```