# Splitting a String to match date format in a List in Java

Tags: java, list, date, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of strings which I am going to write to a CSV file. The list elements has a String like this,

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("one, Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT, last");
list1.add("two, newlast, Aug 22, 2018 11:08:52 PDT");
```

But the problem is when I write to CSV file, `"Aug 21"` and `"2018 11:08:51"` gets separated into the different column.

I need it like `"Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT"`.

Also, the index might change, it is not sure Aug 21 will always come at the same position in the list.

I tried the below code to fix this, It is Working. But is there any better way to fix this, (Instead of splitting to the array and iterating)

```
list1.forEach(s -> {
        String s1[] = s.split(",");
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
            if(isValidMonthDate(s1[i])==true) {
                if(s1[i+1]!=null && !s1[i+1].isEmpty()) {
                    if(isValidYearTime(s1[i+1])) {
                        s1[i] = s1[i].trim();
                        System.out.println("\""+ s1[i] +","+s1[i+1]+"\""); //i will concatenate this string and write to csv
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public static boolean isValidMonthDate(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");       dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isValidYearTime(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");        
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am able to get output,

```
"Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT"
"Aug 22, 2018 11:08:52 PDT"
```

Is there any better way to achieve this without splitting to aarray and iterating it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to wrap the dates in quotes. Since date has comma in it.

Comment: (pst just a tip: If you have nested `if` statements like that, merge them all into one single `if`. much easier to read.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String containing comma inputting in to the csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103224/string-containing-comma-inputting-in-to-the-csv-file)

Comment: @JackFlamp exactly - and statements...

Comment: *... it is not sure Aug 21 will always comes at same position in the list..*  - that makes it pretty difficult. Are you creating the csv file yourself? If yes, format it with semicolon, like `"one; Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT; last"`

Comment: Have a look at the various CSV libraries out there (e.g. Apache Commons CSV) which should make reading and writing CSV files with escaped values (i.e. quoted dates in your case) much easier.

Comment: Use a proper csv parser - there are rules which cover this scenario

Comment: With an ambiguous input format there is little you can do to get it 100% correct.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the normal date parser to attempt parsing at each index using a parse position, and see where it succeeds.

As I try to ignore the old date api nowadays, here's a simple demo with the new one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(
        "Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT",
        "one, Aug 21, 2018 11:08:51 PDT, last",
        "two, newlast, Aug 22, 2018 11:08:52 PDT"
        );
    String formatPattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, Locale.US);

    for(String input : inputs) {
        System.out.println("Processing " + input);

        int[] matchStartEnd = null;
        TemporalAccessor temp = null;

        // check all possible offsets i in the input string
        for(int i = 0, n = input.length() - formatPattern.length(); i <= n; i++) {
            try {
                ParsePosition pt = new ParsePosition(i);
                temp = pattern.parse(input, pt); 
                matchStartEnd = new int[] { i, pt.getIndex() };
                break;
            }
            catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
                // ignore this
            }
        }
        if(matchStartEnd != null) {
            System.out.println("  Found match at indexes " + matchStartEnd[0] + " to " + matchStartEnd[1]);
            System.out.println("  temporal accessor is " + temp);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("  No match");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When output, put the date in quotes.  That's how CSV escapes them.

To parse your input, use a regex.  This one will read each date or word, and consume the comma separator

```
(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4})|(\w+),?
```

You can elaborate with more parenthesis to pre-parse your date.  If the first expression matches, it's the date.  I will leave it to OP to order the final CSV.

Here the regex in Javascript for POC.  I know the question is Java, but REGEX is same.

```js
// read word or date followed by comma
const rx = /(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4})|(\w+),?/g

const input = ['one, Aug 2, 1999, two', 'three, four, Aug 3, 2000', 'Aug 3, 2010, five, six']

let csv2 = ''

input.forEach(it => {
  let parts = []
  let m2 = rx.exec(it)
  while (m2) {
    parts.push(m2[1] || m2[2])
    m2 = rx.exec(it)
  }
  csv2 += parts.map(it => '"' + it + '"').join(',') + '\n'
})

console.log(csv2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/pXiC5m/1) to extract the date:

```
^(.*?)(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} PDT)(.*?)$
```

And `Stream::map` to extract the date and try to parse it. Don't forget to filter `null` values out since they didn't pass the parsing.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
list1.stream()
     .map(s -> { 
         try {
             return sdf.parse(s.replaceAll("^(.*?)(\\w{3} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} PDT)(.*?)$", "$2")));
         } catch (ParseException e) {} return null; })
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I suggest you wrap the `try-catch` and the Regex extracting into a separate method.

```
static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);

static Date validate(String date) {
    String s = date.replaceAll("^(.*?)(\\w{3} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} PDT)(.*?)$", "$2");
    try {
        return sdf.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) { }
    return null;
}
```

... which significantly simplifies the Stream:

```
list1.stream()
     .map(Main::validate)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```